# Jest | Test if moment function has been called and if the return output is the correct one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a moment function to format a date I get from the server in milliseconds. I am trying to tests with Enzyme and Jest, if the `moment function` has been called(1), and if the output of the called function is the expected one.

Here is my component:

```
/* eslint-disable react/default-props-match-prop-types */
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import ILicense from 'user/dto/ILicense';

export interface Props {
  license?: ILicense;
}

const LicenseInfo = <T extends object>({ license }: Props & T): JSX.Element => (
  <Fragment>
        <table className="table col-6 my-5">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Valid Until:</td>
              <td className="font-weight-bold" id="expiry">
                {moment(expiredAt).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZZ')}
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </Fragment>
);

ComponentMoment.defaultProps = {
  expiredAt: null,
};

export default ComponentMoment;
```

And here is my test:

```
  it('expect to show the expiration date if expiredAt is provided', () => {
    const moment = jest.mock('moment', () => () => ({ format: () => '2019–02–28T23:59:58' }));

    const license = {
      expiredAt: 1551391198000,
    };
    const wrapper = mount<ComponentMoment>(<ComponentMoment license={license}>Test</ComponentMoment>);
    wrapper.instance();
    expect(moment).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

That test currently fails with:

```
MatchError: Value must be a mock or a spy, and a huge object with various jest functions.
```

As for the second test, test the actual time, I get a number instead of a string back, and `toString`, is not working.

I also, read this article about moment testing `https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/mocking-moment-js-in-jest-a-simple-one-line-solution-61259ffaaa2`, but I don't really get it.

Can someone help? I am new to testing.. and I get extremely frustrated, cause I don't get the reason, why it failed. Thank you!!

Comment: Hey Dimitris. I know this isn't the answer to your question, but you mentioned being new to testing, and I thought I would give you a piece of advice... as a general rule, you shouldn't test framework code. Trust moment to have tested moment... you have no logic of your own to test there.

Comment: Thank you. Truth be told, I thought of it myself. This past week I found myself in this situation a lot. I get the second test scenario is for moment itself, but if the function is called, is logic of the component itself, or am I wrong?

Comment: Do you have an extra () => in your mock?

Comment: Yeah I had, but that is not the problem. The error, is this: `MatchError: Recieved Value must be a mock or a spy`

Comment: Oh. I'm pretty sure you want format to be format: jest.fn()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, I believe you want format to be created with jest.fn() and then attach it to the moment object.

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect.html#tohavebeencalled